# Cassandra Connection Issue with Spark-jobserver

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark, spark-jobserver

I am new to Spark world and Job Server

My Code :

```
package spark.jobserver 

import java.nio.ByteBuffer 

import scala.collection.JavaConversions._ 
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer 
import scala.collection.immutable.Map 

import org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.ConfigHelper 
import org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlPagingInputFormat 
import org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlConfigHelper 
import org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlOutputFormat 
import org.apache.cassandra.utils.ByteBufferUtil 
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job 

import com.typesafe.config.{Config, ConfigFactory} 
import org.apache.spark._ 
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._ 
import scala.util.Try 

object CassandraCQLTest extends SparkJob{ 

  def main(args: Array[String]) {   
    val sc = new SparkContext("local[4]", "CassandraCQLTest") 
    sc.addJar("/extra_data/spark-cassandra-connector/spark-cassandra-connector-java/target/scala-2.10/spark-cassandra-connector-java-assembly-1.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"); 
    val config = ConfigFactory.parseString("") 
    val results = runJob(sc, config) 
    println("Result is " + "test") 
  } 

  override def validate(sc: SparkContext, config: Config): SparkJobValidation = { 
    Try(config.getString("input.string")) 
      .map(x => SparkJobValid) 
      .getOrElse(SparkJobInvalid("No input.string config param")) 
  } 

  override def runJob(sc: SparkContext, config: Config): Any = { 
    val cHost: String = "localhost" 
    val cPort: String = "9160" 
    val KeySpace = "retail" 
    val InputColumnFamily = "ordercf" 
    val OutputColumnFamily = "salecount" 

    val job = new Job() 
    job.setInputFormatClass(classOf[CqlPagingInputFormat]) 
    ConfigHelper.setInputInitialAddress(job.getConfiguration(), cHost) 
    ConfigHelper.setInputRpcPort(job.getConfiguration(), cPort) 
    ConfigHelper.setInputColumnFamily(job.getConfiguration(), KeySpace, InputColumnFamily) 
    ConfigHelper.setInputPartitioner(job.getConfiguration(), "Murmur3Partitioner") 
    CqlConfigHelper.setInputCQLPageRowSize(job.getConfiguration(), "3") 

    /** CqlConfigHelper.setInputWhereClauses(job.getConfiguration(), "user_id='bob'") */ 

    /** An UPDATE writes one or more columns to a record in a Cassandra column family */ 
    val query = "UPDATE " + KeySpace + "." + OutputColumnFamily + " SET sale_count = ? " 
    CqlConfigHelper.setOutputCql(job.getConfiguration(), query) 

    job.setOutputFormatClass(classOf[CqlOutputFormat]) 
    ConfigHelper.setOutputColumnFamily(job.getConfiguration(), KeySpace, OutputColumnFamily) 
    ConfigHelper.setOutputInitialAddress(job.getConfiguration(), cHost) 
    ConfigHelper.setOutputRpcPort(job.getConfiguration(), cPort) 
    ConfigHelper.setOutputPartitioner(job.getConfiguration(), "Murmur3Partitioner") 

    val casRdd = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(job.getConfiguration(), 
      classOf[CqlPagingInputFormat], 
      classOf[java.util.Map[String,ByteBuffer]], 
      classOf[java.util.Map[String,ByteBuffer]]) 


    val productSaleRDD = casRdd.map { 
      case (key, value) => { 
        (ByteBufferUtil.string(value.get("prod_id")), ByteBufferUtil.toInt(value.get("quantity"))) 
      } 
    } 
    val aggregatedRDD = productSaleRDD.reduceByKey(_ + _) 
    aggregatedRDD.collect().foreach { 
      case (productId, saleCount) => println(productId + ":" + saleCount) 
    } 

    val casoutputCF  = aggregatedRDD.map { 
      case (productId, saleCount) => { 
        val outColFamKey = Map("prod_id" -> ByteBufferUtil.bytes(productId)) 
        val outKey: java.util.Map[String, ByteBuffer] = outColFamKey 
        var outColFamVal = new ListBuffer[ByteBuffer] 
        outColFamVal += ByteBufferUtil.bytes(saleCount) 
        val outVal: java.util.List[ByteBuffer] = outColFamVal 
       (outKey, outVal) 
      } 
    } 

    casoutputCF.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile( 
        KeySpace, 
        classOf[java.util.Map[String, ByteBuffer]], 
        classOf[java.util.List[ByteBuffer]], 
        classOf[CqlOutputFormat], 
        job.getConfiguration() 
      ) 
    casRdd.count 
  } 
}
```

When I push the Jar using spark-jobServer and execute it I get this on spark-jobserver terminal

```
job-server[ERROR] Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/cassandra/hadoop/cql3/CqlPagingInputFormat 
job-server[ERROR] at spark.jobserver.CassandraCQLTest$.runJob(CassandraCQLTest.scala:46) 
job-server[ERROR] at spark.jobserver.CassandraCQLTest$.runJob(CassandraCQLTest.scala:21) 
job-server[ERROR] at spark.jobserver.JobManagerActor$$anonfun$spark$jobserver$JobManagerActor$$getJobFuture$4.apply(JobManagerActor.scala:235) 
job-server[ERROR] at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24) 
job-server[ERROR] at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24) 
job-server[ERROR] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) 
job-server[ERROR] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) 
job-server[ERROR] at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 
job-server[ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlPagingInputFormat 
job-server[ERROR] at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366) 
job-server[ERROR] at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) 
job-server[ERROR] at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
job-server[ERROR] at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354) 
job-server[ERROR] at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425) 
job-server[ERROR] at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358) 
job-server[ERROR] ... 8 more
```

I have already added the $EXTRA_JAR variable to my cassandra-spark-connector-assembly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include all your dependent jar files (comma separated list) when you submit your program into Spark.
Assume if your project structure is as below.

```
 simpleapp
  - src/main/java
    - org.apache.spark.examples
      - SimpleApp.java
  - lib
    - dependent.jars (you can put all dependent jars inside lib   directory)
  - target
    - simpleapp.jar (after compiling your source)
```

So you can use below command.

```
spark-submit --jars $(echo lib/*.jar | tr ' ' ',' ) --class org.apache.spark.examples.SimpleApp --master local[2]  target/simpleapp.jar
```

Further you can see the jar distribution using spark web console, go to your program -> Environment and figure out the jar file complained by spark is already there or not.

Answer (score 0):

The CqlPagingInputFormat is in cassandra-all version 2.0.4 and is not found in further versions.
At run time ur application is taking cassandra version greater than 2.0.4.
your have to add this dependency to ur pom:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.cassandra</groupId>
  <artifactId>cassandra-all</artifactId>   
  <version>2.0.4</version>
```

to get this class.

but I don't guarntee other things will work fine.